# Setting env variable in R

Tags: r

I have a basic query.

I have 2 env variable in my R env
.r.ab.env and .r.cd.env

I have a "type" variable which can have values "ab" or "cd". Now what I want to achieve is

```
 function(type){
   # type value ( ab or cd) below should not come in double quote w.r.t type param
  .r.type.env$var1 <- ....
 }
```

I don't want to hard code type value using if else or conditional operator for the same. i.e. I don't want to do the same in following way :

```
 function(type)
 {
   if(type = "ab")
     .r.ab.env$var1 <- ......
   else
      .r.cd.env$var1 <- ......
 }
```

Comment: Your question title is misleading. Your question doesn't appear to be about setting [environment variables](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/EnvVar.html).

Comment: Since, its about setting env var name, thats why I put this subject line. Feel free to suggest me an edit for the same. I am good with that.

Answer (score 0):

this could be a start

```
 ab <-environment()
 cd <- environment()

 assign_to_env <- function(type){
   # calculation of value here 
   assign("var1", value, envir = get(type))
 }
```

of course, this assumes that you already have your environments beforehand but that's how I interpreted the question.